# How to create a raw device as a file in the filesystem?

Tags: redhat, raw-disk

I have heard there is a way to create a file in a filesystem which will can be configured as a raw device?
Does anyone know the commands for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is, it's one of the "loopback device" capability.

You need to create the file and then associate it with a loopback using "losetup".

Eg:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/file bs=4k count=20k
losetup /dev/loop0 /path/to/file
```